# Unable to add Config Vars on heroku

Tags: heroku

From past 3 days Iam trying to add Config Vars on Heroku but it keeps saying, "Item could not be updated:Unknown Error. Please contact support". When I try to contact customer support it says support for free hosting is provided by community. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Config vars have some limitations. They cannot be too long and you cannot have too many. That's the only possible error I can think of that keeps happening

Comment: Iam only trying to add 2 variables and I have hosted other projects on Heroku with same variables.

Comment: That's the only limitation regarding config vars I am aware of. Try to set the config var via app dashboard and through CLI.